# MySQL Query for group participant COUNT and IF isParticipant statement

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, count, left-join

I have a problem with a MySQL query and I am not able to solve it.

The initial situation is as follows:
I have a table with users and a table with groups. Both tables are connected by a many through (group_participant) table.

The following query works:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    COUNT(participant.groupId) AS participantsCount
FROM 
    group 
LEFT JOIN 
    group_participant participant 
ON 
    participant.groupId = id
GROUP BY
    id
```

Now I want to extend this query with a filter that only returns the entries in which I am a participant, but the counting of participants should not be affected.

Afterwards it should be possible to specify a flag in the Select if the user is a participant or not

It should be something like:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    COUNT(participant.groupId) AS participantsCount, 
    IF(participant.userId = "87b67168-0d7d-46c5-9437-29f996b3d85d", 1, 0) AS isParticipant
FROM 
    group 
LEFT JOIN 
    group_participant participant
ON 
    participant.groupId = id
WHERE 
    participant.userId = "87b67168-0d7d-46c5-9437-29f996b3d85d" 
GROUP BY
    id
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that: MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the groups that you participate then remove the `WHERE` clause and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT 
    g.id, 
    COUNT(gp.userId) AS participantsCount
FROM group g LEFT JOIN group_participant participant gp
ON gp.groupId = g.id
GROUP BY g.id
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN gp.userId = '87b67168-0d7d-46c5-9437-29f996b3d85d' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

In a database like MySql you can write the `HAVING` clause like this:

```
HAVING MAX(gp.userId = '87b67168-0d7d-46c5-9437-29f996b3d85d') = 1
```

To set the flag:

```
SELECT 
    g.id, 
    COUNT(gp.userId) AS participantsCount,
    MAX(CASE WHEN participant.userId = '87b67168-0d7d-46c5-9437-29f996b3d85d' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS isParticipant
FROM group g LEFT JOIN group_participant participant gp
ON gp.groupId = g.id
GROUP BY g.id
```

or for MySql:

```
MAX(participant.userId = '87b67168-0d7d-46c5-9437-29f996b3d85d') AS isParticipant
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas! It solved the problem. Have a nice day.